# List Search box not appearing

Tags: list, web-part, search

I am working on a migrated site and today my prime concept is to enable search box on list, I tried to enable different ways as explained below but no luck.

1. Edit the list web part ->  miscellaneous sections ->  but I didn't find "Display Search box" option.
2. I followed fellow articles and changed view styles Shaded to Default.

Still I am unable to find the Display Search box option on web part miscellaneous section.

Can anyone know please let me help to enable search box on list?

Comment: Have you inserted the list to the page as an App Part? (Edit page -> Insert -> App Part -> Select your list)

Comment: Hi moe, I didn't try that option because of this site is migrated one and there is a no.of pages has lists added on the site, so going to insert web part with views on each page is difficult and time taken.

Comment: I see. If just possible, you could try this on a test site for example and report the results. I don't know that much about migrations, but I know they aren't always that straight-forward :)

Comment: Hi moe, thanks for your suggestion, I followed your suggestion and I created a page and inserted app part and changed list view style from Shaded to default but still am unable to get search box.

Comment: Do you see the search box if you navigate to your list? Try `http://site.com/Lists/YourList/AllItems.aspx` (or exclude the `AllItems.aspx` and check other available views). I'm beginning to suspect if the list even should have a search box.

Comment: Hi moe, search box not appear for AllItems.aspx (All Items) page itself.

Comment: That truly is some strange behavior. I'm quite sure this is because of the migrated list - as if it would've not got the features the lists have by default. But if you want to stick with the migrated lists (ie. not start using lists created in the new version of your SP), I have unfortunately no recommendations for workarounds.

Comment: Hi moe, I finally done a temporary fix for this , I created a new view as same configuration and deleted the existing web part on the view page and added new one, I know this is not a permanent solution but as short it save my time. Thanks for your help and have a good day.

Comment: If you think this answers to your question, you can add it as an answer, maybe with some details added. The answer doesn't have to be accepted if you feel so. Other users still can find this workaround more easily from answers section.

Answer (score 1):

I finally done a temporary fix for this , I created a new view as same configuration and deleted the existing web part on the view page and added new one, I know this is not a permanent solution but as short it save your time.